# jquery-ui asset not found. How to incorporate assets from rails pipeline into jquery-ui css?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, asset-pipeline

I noticed that locally we were getting errors about 7 different jquery-ui images, e.g. `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/public/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png")`

These assets do actually exist within the jquery-ui file structure.

I have found that changing the url's used within the jquery-ui framework css itself from "`url(/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png`" to "`url(/assets/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png` " or "`url(ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png` " removes the error (though I had to also do a `rake assets:precompile` locally).  However this seems like a bad approach and not the right thing to do.

What is the right approach to resolving these errors?

Comment: This might be helpful http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/jquery-ui-css-and-images-and-rails-asset-pipeline/

Comment: which version of rails and jquery-ui is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final result was:

- delete my local versions.
- add the items to the jquery js and css manifest files.
- use the jquery-ui-rails gems

Answer (score 2):

First off, I highly recommend using the jquery-ui-rails gem to easily roll jquery ui into the assets pipeline.

In your Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails' # jquery ui
end
```

In your app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:

```
*= require jquery.ui.all
```

Note that you can only require the parts of jquery ui you use, like the progressbar or datepicker, ala `jquery.ui.progressbar`

And in app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

Now run `bundle install` and voila! You're set!

Comment: This looked great but didn't work :(  I also updated this answer with the correct names/locations of the files (the gem 'jquery-ui-rails' addition was listed as being for routes.rb but fairly clearly it should be Gemfile.rb, correct?).

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, the gem should be added in the Gemfile. Did you run bundle install?

Comment: Yes, and I tried reappling everything as detailed but I still get `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/ui-bg_highlight-so
ft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png"):`

Answer (score 0):

Observe what path is 404 Not Found in your browser, and then make sure the query-ui theme's /images directory is either moved or linked to that path in the Rails app.

**Example**

I experience 404 for:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png
```

My jquery-ui theme directory is in /vendor, so the real path to the images is:

```
RAILS_ROOT/vendor/assets/stylesheets/ui-lightness/images
```

So, to fix the 404, put a symbolic link to that directory where it's expected:

```
% cd vendor/assets/stylesheets
% ln -s ui-lightness/images images
```

Now, that URL serves the images.